# Garage Band does not have Podcast creation option

Tags: garageband

I had Garage Band in Snowleopard which had option to create podcast. I upgraded OSX and get new Garage Band which does not have such option. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup, you can use the older version of it: it should work fine. Alternatively, you could use a number of other tools: the older podcast creation apps, any number of audio editing suites, etc. It largely depends on why you want to use a given app and why.

Comment: Which version is `older` version?

Comment: whichever one you used in Snow Leopard

Comment: @Volatil3 Any version that meets you needs :P. But if your Snow Leopard workflow was what you were using, use those apps.